# Passing Datagridview rows to first form from second form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, telerik, telerik-grid

I have two forms, say `Form1` and `Form2`.

On `Form2` I have a `Radgridview` with some rows.

How do I send a row from this form to `form1` which has a `datagridview`?

Comment: do you need UI rows, or related data?

Comment: UI Rows not related data :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the data. I never liked it, and I don't like any of these, maybe excluding delegates. From an codeproject article, there are 4 popular ways to do that:

1. Using constructor
2. Using objects
3. Using properties
4. Using delegates

To see how each of them work, I will just link you to the article, instead of copying everything.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

If you already know how to do that, then you just have to select the rows and pass them. I don't know telerik, but it probably has something like RadGridRow, in radGrid1.Rows[0]. You will just properly change the index and pass these rows to another grid(if that's what you want to do).